# Issue with calling Dojo ContentPane Children inside BorderContainer

Tags: dojo, border-container, contentpane

I am trying to use a BorderContainer and call a couple of ContentPanes, utilizing their region style, inside. However, I am having issues with that code which looks like this:

```
function getWindowContent(graphic) {
        var bc = new dijit.layout.BorderContainer({
            style: "width:600px;height:600px;background-color:lightblue;"
        }, dojo.create("div"));

    //display attribute information1
    var german = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
      region: "leading",
      content: "<p>Hallo Welt!</p><p>info</p><p>info</p><p>info</p>"
    }, dojo.create("div"));

    //display attribute information2
    var french = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
      region: "center",
      content: "<p>Bonjour tout le monde!</p><p>info</p><p>info</p><p>info</p>"
    }, dojo.create("div"));

    //display attribute information3
    var english = new dijit.layout.ContentPane({
      region: "trailing",
      content: "<p>Hello World!</p><p>info</p><p>info</p><p>info</p>"
    }, dojo.create("div"));

    bc.startup();

    bc.addChild(german);
    bc.addChild(french);
    bc.addChild(english);

    return bc.domNode;
  }
```

The only child that appears properly is the 'english' one while the 'german' one does not show up at all and the 'french' one is seriously compressed. Does anyone have an ideas as to how I might be able to fix this?